# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'forEach' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, master-pages

I have an aspx Master page application where I have two dropdownlist controls in the asp:content section of the child aspx page. One of the controls is populated from SQL database. The other is populated based on the item selected from the first dropdown. I am trying to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19040248/3929962) in my code, however I am getting an error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'forEach' of
>   undefined or null reference

How can I get the city names to be displayed based on State selected?
My code block is:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        AL = new Array('Birmingham', 'Montgomery', 'Tuscaloosa');
        FL = new Array('Miami', 'FtLauderdale', 'Jacksonville');
        GA = new Array('Atlanta', 'Macon', 'Athens');

        populateSelect();

        $(function () {

            $('#ddlState').change(function () {
                populateSelect();
            });

        });

        function populateSelect() {
            category = $('#ddlState').val();
            $('#ddlCity').html('');

            eval(category).forEach(function (t) {
                $('#ddlCity').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
            });
        }
    </script>  

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" CssClass="stdFldWidth" onchange="setFDFlag()">
</asp:DropDownList>    

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" CssClass="stdFldWidth" DataSourceID="dsUSState"
    DataTextField="US_State" DataValueField="State_ID" AutoPostBack="true" > 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Update:

```
Protected Sub ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlType.SelectedIndexChanged
If ddlState.SelectedValue = "FL" Then
    DisplayRegulation(FL)
End If
```

Comment: Never, I said never, use `eval()`. If you need to use it there's something wrong in your code.

Comment: Also, when you inspect your dropdownlists in the browser, check if their IDs didn't get changed. It's a common thing when using ASP.NET.

Comment: @MelanciaUK the id in view source is ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlState

Comment: So your jQuery selectors won't pick them as they're. You can give them a unique class and use it instead of the ID.

Comment: I've removed my answer because I don't believe it would solve all your problems. It's unclear to me what else could be messing up with your solution, but for sure you can't use these IDs as jQuery selectors.

Comment: you're answer was 80% working coupled with @sebnukem . It would help me if you put it back

Comment: I've undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common issue with `ASP.NET` pages, specially if you use `MasterPages`.

The generated pages will have their elements `IDs` changed.

One solution for your problem is to give these elements a unique `class` and use it in the selector instead of their `IDs`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" CssClass="stdFldWidth ddlCity" onchange="setFDFlag()">
</asp:DropDownList>    

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" CssClass="stdFldWidth ddlState" DataSourceID="dsUSState"
    DataTextField="US_State" DataValueField="State_ID" AutoPostBack="true" > 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

...

```
$(function () {
    var states = {
        AL: ['Birmingham', 'Montgomery', 'Tuscaloosa'],
        FL: ['Miami', 'FtLauderdale', 'Jacksonville'],
        GA: ['Atlanta', 'Macon', 'Athens']
    };

    function populateSelect() {
        $('.ddlCity').empty();

        var stateSelected = $('.ddlState').val();

        if (stateSelected) {
            states[stateSelected].forEach(function (sel) {
                $('<option>').val(sel).text(sel).appendTo($('.ddlCity'));
            });
        }
    }

    populateSelect();

    $('.ddlState').on('change', function() { 
        populateSelect();

        return true;
    });
});
```

**Edited** using @sebnukem recommendation to keep the data in an `object`, so you can get rid of the `eval()`.

**Updated** by placing the whole code within the `jQuery` document ready event handler.

**Updated** by returning true in the `jQuery` onchange event handler for the `DropDownList`, to carry on with the `PostBack`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/fwtduuot/3/)

Comment: I updated my original post with the codebehind. I tried adding the values to ddlCity in the codebehind, but it didnt work. I was thinking jquery would be an easier option.

Comment: Your codebehind doesn't seem to be taking part in the problem stated in the question.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Which part? I've updated the answer, now having all the Javascript/jQuery code within the document ready event handler - `$(function () { });`. And I don't believe you have an issue in your codebehind that could be messing up with this code - causing the Javascript error stated in your question.

Comment: After you rolled back the changes, did you put back the classes in the DropDownLists?

Comment: The updated JQuery does not run when the page is loaded.... meaning  when I run the application and the page loads, ddlCity is blank.

Comment: Ah, sure. I've forgotten to add the call to the `populateSelect()`. Try the updated answer (just edited) again please.

Comment: Ok, that your last response now works. I think I am at the last issue. When I change ddlState to a different value, ddlCity goes blank. That is where I think the codebehind is interrupting the JQuery. Would you agree?

Comment: It could be. Try to debug both codebehind and client-side to see step-by-step what's going on.

Comment: well, when I set AutoPostBack = false, everything works perfectly. When I set it back to true, I run into the issue in my last comment

Comment: I am trying out this suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510926/trigger-jquery-code-on-autopostback-true

Comment: This one might be helpful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203988/jquery-dropdown-selector-autopostback

Comment: wow... I think that does it. Thanks very much for your help!!

Comment: No problems. I'm glad I could help. The thing is the `AutoPostBack` adds an `onchange` event handler to the `DropDownList`, and it was being broken by the jQuery call. If you return true, it will carry on normally.

Answer (score 2):

Never use `eval`. Store your data in an object instead:

```
var states = {
    'AL': ['Birmingham', 'Montgomery', 'Tuscaloosa'],
    'FL': ['Miami', 'FtLauderdale', 'Jacksonville'],
    'GA': ['Atlanta', 'Macon', 'Athens']
};

function populateSelect() {
    var category = $('#ddlState').val(); // selected state

    if (category && states[category]) {
        $('#ddlCity').html('');
        states[category].forEach(function (t) {
            $('#ddlCity').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
        });
    } else {
        console.log('invalid state input: '+category); 
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('#ddlState').change(function () {
        populateSelect();
    });
    populateSelect();
});
```

I am assuming that the `<asp:DropDownList>` element does produce an HTML element with the specified ID.

Comment: then that means that the `category` value doesn't match any key in the `states` object. Check your value with a `console.log('state = '+category);` statement.